# Docker run vs pull

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I am a beginner in docker and referring [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-18-04) to install and understand basics but I am little confused about `run` and `pull` command.

What is the difference between `docker run` and `docker pull` commands for Docker images?

Comment: What's the specific confusion? `docker run` runs a container/command. `docker pull` pulls a docker image (or repository) from the docker registry. They're not similar at all.

Comment: @Dave: `run` can be confusing, because it will do a `pull` if it can't find the image locally.

Comment: @halfer I guess; I never saw anything particularly confusing about it--to me it makes sense that `run` would `pull` if there are missing dependencies. *shrug*

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`docker run` runs an instance of a container. In order to do that it will `pull` all the required images needed to run the container (i.e. base images) in the background if they are not part of the local cache.

`docker pull` will fetch/pull an image from the docker registry.

Think of it similar to `git fetch` and `git pull` if you have worked with `git`.
`git pull` will do `git fetch` (and `git merge`)

Answer (score 6):

From the docs:

**[`docker run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/):**

> The `docker run` command first `creates` a writeable container layer over the specified image, and then `starts` it using the specified command. A stopped container can be restarted with all its previous changes intact using `docker start`. See `docker ps -a` to view a list of all containers.

If the image you are trying to run is not downloaded yet it will be automatically fetched with `pull`.

**[`docker pull`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/):**

> Most of your images will be created on top of a base image from the Docker Hub registry.
>
> Docker Hub contains many pre-built images that you can `pull` and try without needing to define and configure your own.
>
> To download a particular image, or set of images (i.e., a repository), use `docker pull`.

So `docker pull` will download or update an image.

Answer (score 2):

Pull will download new versions of images if there are any, while run will only download an image if you don't have a local copy.